# How to DRYing action buttons in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, dry

I have a dozen different Views/Controllers for administrator. In every view I have got something like this:

```
<%= link_to edit_topic_path(topic) do %>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
<% end %> |
<%= link_to topic, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" do %>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
<% end %>
```

Now my question is, How can I DRY this so I just pass some vars or object to a method and generate the above code for different views.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should crate a partial

`_controls.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to path do %>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
<% end %> |
<%= link_to model, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" do %>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
<% end %>
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
<%= render :partial => "controls", :locals => {:path => edit_topic_path(topic), :model => topic} %>
```

Comment: hmm, what about the model that is called in the delete? should I pass it from :locals?

Comment: Sure, you can send as many arguments as you want: `:locals => {:path => edit_topic_path(topic), :model => topic}`